# convert os.popen command to a subprocess.Popen instance

Tags: python, django, linux, unix, popen

According to python docs http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html, it's recommended to replace os.popen with the Popen class, right now I have the following command:

```
import os
c = "openssl dgst -sha1 -sign /foo/1 /bar/1 | openssl enc -base64 -A"
my_value = os.popen(c).read()
```

I understand that Popen takes the command as a list of string arguments, how ever it breaks when I try to pass pipe ("|"), I also understand this is caused because "|" has a special meaning in bash, how ever not sure how to solve this issue.

The other issue is Popen instances don't have `read` method so I'm not sure what is the way to see the output.

I am using Django Framework, so If there is also a function in the framework that may help is also an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Replacing the shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) section in the documentation, you'll see that your example could be written as follows using `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE                                        
p_dgst = Popen("openssl dgst -sha1 -sign /foo/1 /bar/1".split(),
               stdout=PIPE)
p_enc =  Popen("openssl enc -base64 -A".split(),
               stdin=p_dgst.stdout, stdout.PIPE)
my_value = p_enc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Is there some documentation why `os.popen` should be replaced? The code above looks more complex than the simple `os.popen` call.

Answer (score 2):

To get subprocess to run shell pipelines, use the option `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```